# No Twitter authorization prompt when using rtweet package

Tags: r, twitter, authorization, rtweet

When using rtweet, I am not prompted to sign into twitter at any point.  As a result I receive a : Error: is.request(signed_req) is not TRUE error. Any suggestions on how to overcome this issue?

I have been following the getting started examples on cran with no success.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post some of the code you tried? According to http://rtweet.info/:

> The first time you make an API request—e.g., search_tweets(), stream_tweets(), get_followers()—a browser window will open

You may need to reinstall from the github.

Comment: ,thanks for the response.  I was trying to follow those instructions here is the code that I ran:
 `rt <- search_tweets(
  "#libyanslavetrade", n = 18000, include_rts = FALSE)` 

 I also did reinstall from GitHub, thinking that might be the issue but unfortunately, the same result, no browser window prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar authentication where I was not prompted to login after trying to use `search_tweets()`. However, my error code read:

> Error in oauth_listener(authorize_url, is_interactive) :
>   httpuv package required to capture OAuth credentials.

After installing the `httpuv` package, I reran `search_tweets()` as was able to make a successful call.